# Move background with the player location

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-iphone

I want to move background with  player location in ios . I have implemented the infinite parallax background by using the CCParallax class but i don't need it. I want to do something similar to this game http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNRNlLzrKmc.

my game level is large want to parallax up when player will move up. How will i do that please explain me. will i have to use CCCamera or i can do this by using CCParallax class.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows parallax movement, it's just in two dimensions. Commonly parallax movement is only displayed for the X axis.

You simply need to extend your existing parallax code to apply to the Y axis in addition to the X axis.

Comment: Thanks for reply Yes i will apply it for Y axis but my parallax is working infinitely but in my given example have you seen it is moving with the player location how will do this.